# Clearing cache / cookies in GeckoView

Tags: android, kotlin, geckoview

Is there a way of clearing the cache and the cookies from GeckoView? Something comparable to WebView's `CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null)` or `webView.clearCache()`?

I have a customer facing app that should not maintain any data between user sessions but should allow a user to login to websites should they want to. Currently I am able to enforce this behavior by running the GeckoSession in private mode. However, this means that a user could potentially have to login to a site multiple times should they close and then re-open the GeckoView. Also, there are some websites that I display within the GeckoView that show their own alerts should they detect private mode, which I would obviously prefer to avoid.

Comment: Hi Dan, Did you find any way to accomplish this?

Comment: https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/StorageController.ClearFlags.html